# RuntimeError: CUDA error: device assert triggered when trying to train on google colab while using YOLOv5

Tags: python, pytorch

I am not quite sure what is the problem with this one it only occurs once it reaches the testing part of training. I have already tried checking the files and renaming all the files and everything seems to be correct, if anyone could help it would greatly be appreciated. I am using the YOLO repository from GitHub.

```
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:93: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [69,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:93: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [103,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:93: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [104,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:93: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [50,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:93: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [28,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:93: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [29,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
               Class     Images     Labels          P          R     mAP@.5 mAP@.5:.95:  36% 16/45 [00:09<00:16,  1.77it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 625, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "train.py", line 522, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "train.py", line 365, in train
    compute_loss=compute_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py", line 28, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/content/yolov5/val.py", line 186, in run
    targets[:, 2:] *= torch.Tensor([width, height, width, height]).to(device)  # to pixels
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Comment: This isn't a CUDA problem. It looks like something at the Tensor indexing level in Pytorch is going out-of-bounds

Comment: I am not sure why this error persists, I have already trained using the same dataset previously and it worked fine I only added augmented images.

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe you have some very small boxes in your labels, and the augmentation is creating some zero-sized versions of them? I have a similar problem I'm looking at just now - will add an answer if I solve it

Comment: I fixed my apparently identical issue by noticing that there were some label files with incorrect label indices, i.e. with label numbers greater than the set defined in your data/*.yaml file where the labels are defined.